# Got DNS error when use cmd

Tags: windows-10, dns, python, cmd.exe

Sometime when I use `cmd` or `python`, I get a error:

> DNS server not authoritative for zone.

How can I fix it? I'm using Windows 10.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As one user on Microsoft Community [said](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/dns-server-not-authoritative-for-zone-on-command/5b3eaab4-57ac-4099-a2d4-606a5e9e3f9b):

> Sounds like a misleading error message, probably caused by a corrupt system file or less possibly malware.

If you type on CMD: `sfc /scannow`, it should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this method with cmd, its stopped at 45% and show that some errors could not be fixed. Its also give me a log file, I will find it and upload it as soon as possible. I also tried this method with powershell, but no result found. Nothing fixed

Comment: I found it. But I'm not sure if it does contain any personal information? Like, IP address os something? Should I upload it here?

Comment: @NguyễnHoàn if you could take a look at that, it's best to do so because it could contain some personal info. but you can upload it to some service like Pastebin and add in your question.

Comment: I did a scan again, this time nothing found and I used BKAV to take a deep scan too. Still no result. And the error haven't been solved